# R: How to define + sign as an operator to connect strings like in Python?

Tags: r

Since I have to use `paste` function heavily in practice, I wonder whether we can use a specific sign or operator like `"+"`or `"++"` to connect strings like in Python.

So we can have

```
con = "a" + "b"
```

then `con` becomes `"a b"` or `"ab"`.

And would there be any side effects if we do so?

Comment: If you don't mind using the percent method `'%+%' <- function(x,y) paste(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite "+" operation but this is not a recommend method.

A very quick implementation as below. More general, you need to handle different inputs in the function and return the original "+" when the inputs are not strings.

```
"+" <- function(a, b) {
  paste(a, b)
}
> "12" + "34"
[1] "12 34"
```

Comment: I guess If we use `++`, there will be less likely to cause side effects.